# Making links with php?

Tags: php, date, for-loop

I want to have this kind of links

```
<li><a href="arhiva?year=2009">Kamp 2009/10</a></li>
<li><a href="arhiva?year=2007">Kamp 2007/08</a></li>
```

But on next year I want to automatically add new a link

```
<li><a href="arhiva?year=2011">Kamp 2011/12</a></li>
```

How to to do that with a PHP `for` loop, I have variable `$today = date("Y");`

Comment: How are you generating these links?

Comment: I want to create link with for loop the last year i have in 2007

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
<?php

    $currentYear = date("Y"); // same as your $today variable

    for ($i = 2007; $i < $currentYear; $i++) {
        $nextYear = date("y",mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),   date("d"),   $i+1));
        echo "<li><a href=\"arhiva?year=$i\">Kamp $i/$nextYear</a></li>";
    }
```

Comment: This way i got this   Kamp 2007/08
Kamp 2008/09
Kamp 2009/10
Kamp 2010/11
Kamp 2011/12
Kamp 2012/13

Comment: Just change the `$i <= $currentYear` to `$i < $currentYear` (I updated the answer). And **remember** to accept answers that help you.

Comment: @Nacereddine You're wasting your time. He was told many times to accept answers after comments such as "Nice, it works". In none of his questions he ever used the word "Thanks".

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something?

```
<?php
    for ($i = 2007; $i <= $today; $i++) {
        echo "<li><a href=\"arhiva?year=$i\">Kamp $i/08</a></li>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: yes but i want this to change too Kamp 2007/08